# Reading a .txt file in python

Tags: python, filesystems

I have use the following code to read a `.txt` file:

```
f = os.open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), os.O_RDONLY)
```

And when I want to output the content I use this:

```
os.read(f, 10);
```

Which means that this method reads 10 bytes from the beginning of the file on. While I need to read the content as much as it is, using some values such as `-1` and so. What should I do?

Comment: Why you don't use the open() built-in function and read the file line by line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Call `os.read()` repeatedly.
2. Open the file using the [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) built-in (as opposed to [`os.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open)), and just call [`f.read()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) with no arguments.

The second approach carries certain risk, in that you might run into memory issues if the file is very large.